# insert 0 into successive row with same fields value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table containing the following line:

[image]

I'd like to create a view that displays the following result (without changing my original table) :

[image]

For each line having the same id,day,month and year I'd like to leave a single line with the cost and count and insert 0 in the others.

Comment: For any given `(id, day, month)` combo - which is the **first** row that should keep its value? The one with the earliest `datetimeIN` ?

Comment: the order of row keeping value is not important my objectif is just to keeping one. So for example yes you can use the earliest datetimeIN For any given (id, day, month,year)

Comment: @user1374633 Did you check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10724557/1405491)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a portable approach not requiring `PARTITION`. I have assumed you will not have the same `datetimeIN` value for more than one row in a group:

```
select t.id, t.day, t.month, t.year,
    case when tm.id is null then 0 else t.cost end as cost,
    case when tm.id is null then 0 else t.Count end as Count,
    t.datetimeIN, t.datetimeOUT
from MyTable t
left outer join (
    select id, day, month, year, min(datetimeIN) as minIN
    from MyTable
    group by id, day, month, year
) tm on t.id = tm.id
    and t.day = tm.day
    and t.month = tm.month
    and t.year = tm.year
    and t.datetimeIN = tm.minIN
```

Comment: @user1374633 Seems like this is not perfect. Please check my answer with SQL Profiler details...Don't mind RedFilter, It's just to confirm from you that Am I moving in right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT id, day, month, year,
  CASE WHEN nNum = 1 then cost else 0 end as cost,
  CASE WHEN nNum = 1 then "Count" else 0 end as "Count",
  datetimeIN, datetimeOUT
FROM (
  SELECT id, day, month, year,
    cost, "Count", datetimeIN, datetimeOUT,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id, day, month, year
                       ORDER BY datetimeIN) as nNum
  FROM TableName
) A
```

It uses `row_number()` to number the rows, and then a `CASE` statement to single out the first one and make it behave differently.

**[See it working on SQL Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6fc8/5)**

Comment: THX for your solution but that insert 0 in all count and cost ! I want to keep one for each ligne having different (id, day, month,year)

Comment: @user1374633 - sorry about that, fixed the query.

Answer (score 0):

or, using a common table expression:

```
    with    commonTableExp ([day], [month], [year], minDate) as (
            select  [day], [month], [year], min(datetimeIn)
            from    #temp
            group by [day], [month], [year])
    select  id,
            dt.[day],
            dt.[month],
            dt.[year],
            case when datetimein = minDate then [cost] else 0 end,
            case when datetimein = minDate then [count] else 0 end,
            dateTimeIn
    from    #temp dt join commonTableExp cte on 
                dt.[day] = cte.[day] and
                dt.[month] = cte.[month] and
                dt.[year] = cte.[year]
    order by dateTimeIn
```

Answer (score -2):

### Query

```
Select id, [day], [month], [year], Case When K.RowID = 1 Then [cost] Else 0 End as Cost, Case When K.RowID = 1 Then [count] Else 0 End as [count], [DateTimeIN], [DateTimeOut] From
(
    select ROW_NUMBER() Over(Partition by id, [day], [month], [year] Order by ID ) as RowID, * From Testing
)K

Drop table Testing
```

### **[Click here to see SQL Profiler details for Red Filter's Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MnSN.png)**

### **[Click here to see SQL Profiler details for my Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcUfD.png)**

**[For More Information You can see SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6772b/1)**

Comment: This is equivalent to the answer I posted a few hours ago.

Comment: @JakeFeasel Please see my SQL Fiddle. It is testing table and that's why I am finally dropping it.